# Indicator function minus probability on an event is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Define 
\begin{align}
\epsilon_j = \mathbb{1}_{A_j} - \mathbb{P}(A_j) = 
\begin{cases}
1- \mathbb{P}(A_j) \qquad &\text{if } \omega \in A_j\\
- \mathbb{P}(A_j) \qquad &\text{otherwise },
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for independent events $(A_i)_{i \geq 1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\epsilon_1, \ldots , \epsilon_n)$ for $n \geq 0$.

Clearly, $(\epsilon_i)_{i \geq 1}$ are independent random variables with
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_j] &= (1 - \mathbb{P}(A_j)) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_j) - \mathbb{P}(A_j) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_j^c) \\
&= (1 - \mathbb{P}(A_j)) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_j) - \mathbb{P}(A_j) \cdot (1 - \mathbb{P}(A_j)) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Now, let $M_n := \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j$.

I am wondering why $(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a martingale. Let $m \leq n$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[M_n \mid \mathcal{F}_m] &= \mathbb{E}[ \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j \mid \mathcal{F}_m] \\
&=^{?}  \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_j \mid \mathcal{F}_m]
\end{align}
How to find that $\mathbb{E}[M_n \mid \mathcal{F}_m] = \sum_{j=1}^m \epsilon_j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $j>m$ then $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_j|\mathcal{F_m}]=\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_j]=0$ since $\varepsilon_j$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_m}$. And if $j\leq m$ then $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_j|\mathcal{F_m}]=\varepsilon_j$ since $\varepsilon_j$ is $\mathcal{F_m}$-measurable.